# How to convert decimal number from the accessor to react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using react table. On my data, I have fields that have decimal numbers. I need to apply the function of round off on the data of the decimal numbers. I hope you could help me. Thank you

```
   const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
          {
            Header: 'Rank',
            id: 'index',
            accessor: (function (_row, i) { return i + 1; })
          
        },
        
          {
            Header: "Username",
            accessor: "username"
          },
          {
            Header: "Score",
            accessor: 'score',
            Cell: (row) => {
              return <div>{Math.round(row)}</div>;
            },
          },
          
        ],
        []
      );
```

Comment: What's your question? Seems like youre already using `Math.round`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed to `Cell` takes the first argument as an object with more data. To round the number by passing a funciton to `Cell`, use:

```js
Cell: (obj) => Math.round(obj.value)
```

Or pass a function to the `accessor`:

```js
accessor: (obj) => Math.round(obj.score)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.ceil()` if you want to round a number up to the next largest integer